# Cakephp, work with render view

Tags: php, cakephp, render, routes

I would like to know how can I fix this.. 
When a user enter with "aboutClass", Cakephp inform this error "about_class.ctp was not found"

There is a way to set in run time "aboutClass" like "aboutClass.ctp" or "aboutclass.ctp" without lowercase function in php?

Sorry my english..
Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: use `about_class.ctp` and only call it using  `/controller_name/about_class` (one should not use the other way of calling it to avoid duplicate content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark stated you will have to use

```
about_class.ctp
```

The documentation says, "the conventional view file name is the lowercased and underscored version of the action name." I don't know if this behavior can be changed but I would suggest you stick with the convention.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html for more details.